# Hiding SVG image coordinates in HTML 5 Canvas

Tags: svg, html5-canvas

I am adding a SVG image in HTML 5 Canvas. Now I don't want any user to see the coordinates of the image by any means; if user presses F12 in google-chrome, it doesn't matter he looks into resources, source code, etc., he shouldn't get the coordinates.

Is there any means of doing this? (Like encrypting and decrypting the code)

Answer (score 1):

> I don't want any user to see the coordinates of the image by any
>   means...

It's impossible to both let a user see SVG drawn on canvas and also hide the coordinates of that SVG.

They don't even need to press F12. They can just capture the screen display and open it in any paint program which will let them examine any coordinates.